# JavaScript - persistencia en localStorage (no se que me falla) :/

Tags: javascript

bueno el problema es el siguiente: supuestamente con este codigo deberian persistir los datos en pantalla aunque actualice pero esto no ocurre y se borran todos los datos, alguien que puedar ayudarme a entender porque se lo agradeceria mucho. aqui les dejo mi codigo espero puedan ayudarme, en ejecucion de codigo me salio un error donde me dice que el localStore no esta definido y eso tambien es algo que no puedo entender, esa es toda la info que puedo dar sobre mi problema estare pendiente de sus respuestas

```js
const recibe_g = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("recibe_g")) || [];

const render = () => {
  const query = document.getElementById("list_item");
  const map = recibe_g.map((e) => `<li> ${e} </li>`);
  query.innerHTML = map.join("");

  const event = document.querySelectorAll("#list_item li");
  event.forEach((e, i) => {
    e.addEventListener("click", () => {
      e.parentNode.removeChild(e);
      recibe_g.splice(i, 1);
      const stringJson = JSON.stringify(recibe_g);
      localStorage.setItem('recibe_g',stringJson)
      render();
    });
  });
};

window.onload = () =>{
    //este llama al render para iniciar la app con el llamado a esta funtion
  render();
  const recibe_f = document.getElementById("formulario");
  recibe_f.onsubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const salvar = envio_text.value;
    envio_text.value = "";

    recibe_g.push(salvar);
    /* aqui reemplaza el recibe_g por un string luego lo pasa al storage */
    const stringJson = JSON.stringify(recibe_g);
    localStorage.setItem('recibe_g',stringJson)
    render();
  };
}
```

```html
    <!-- formulario -->
    <form action="" id="formulario" class="form_1">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Formulario con Js</legend>
            <label for="">
                <input type="text" name="" id="envio_text">
                <input type="submit" value="Aceptar">
            </label>
        </fieldset>
    </form>

    <!-- list item -->
    <div class="contenedor_list">
        <ul id="list_item" class="list_item">
            
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: ¿En que navegador lo estás probando?

Answer (score 0):

Si funciona:

https://codepen.io/erickms/pen/ZEQpOXj

Para probar online usa codepen. Sino desde algún navegador moderno como chrome, firefox o el nuevo microsoft edge.

Saludos.

Comment: hola, en serio gracias por responder mi duda, pero ahora que veo tu respuesta me hago otra pregunta, Y es porque cuando lo hago en firefox se borran los datos al actualizar y lo mismo para en chromiun de microsoft y tambien en chorme, el unico lugar en donde no pasa esto es Codepen como me muestra tu ejemplo :(